# Spin new threads with custom data

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I am trying to accomplish the following functionality,

I get a `HttpRequest` and based on the request, i will create a new thread and then set some data for this thread [ local and thread specific data ] and then i will spin the thread. In the thread, i must be able to consume that data that i initialized before creating this thread anywhere before this thread ends its life.

I tried this sample and here, the greeting variable inside the thread was null. Any idea of how do i accomplish this process.

```
class Program
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static string greeting = "Greetings from the current thread";

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(greeting); // prints initial value
        greeting = "Goodbye from the main thread";
        Thread t = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();
        Console.WriteLine(greeting); // prints the main thread's copy
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void ThreadMethod()
    {
// I am getting  greeting as null inside this thread method.
        Console.WriteLine(greeting); // prints nothing as greeting initialized on main thread
        greeting = "Hello from the second thread"; // only affects the second thread's copy
        Console.WriteLine(greeting);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I am trying to accomplish something like this

```
class ThreadTest
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var tcp = new ThreadContextData();

        Thread t = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
        tcp.SetThreadContext("hi.. from t1");
        t.Start();
        t.Join();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
        tcp.SetThreadContext("hello.. from t2");
        t2.Start();
        t2.Join();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void ThreadMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new ThreadContextData().GetThreadContextValue());
    }
}

public class ThreadContextData
{
    static ThreadLocal<string> greeting;
    static ThreadContextData()
    {
        greeting = new ThreadLocal<string>(() => "");
    }

    public void SetThreadContext(string contextValue)
    {
        greeting.Value = contextValue;
    }

    public string GetThreadContextValue()
    {
        return greeting.Value;
    }

    public void ClearThreadContextValue()
    {
        greeting.Value = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Thread` class has a method `Start(object)` which you can use to provide parameters to the thread, provided that your thread-routine also takes a parameter:

```
var thr = new Thread(foo);
thr.Start(7);

private void foo(object arg)
{
    int data = (int)arg; // == 7
}
```

However, if you have access to relatively recent .Net platform, you can use inline lambdas to get that less verbose:

```
var thr = new Thread(_ => foo(7, "Marie", 123.44));
thr.Start();

private void foo(int data, string name, double age)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: and now I wanted to explain ThreadStatic, but I see others has already did it :) Once you get the Thread sample running, please try using Tasks from TPL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx they are much more friendly to use than raw threads.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting variable in one thread and trying to read in a new thread. I think you should use something like:

```
 
    Thread thread = new Thread(Start);
    thread.Start("greetings from ...");


    private static void Start(object o)
    {
        var greeting = o as string;
        Console.WriteLine(greeting);
    }
```

Comment: With closures being available in C# I consider the state parameter to be mostly obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

ThreadStatic means that each thread gets it's own version of the variable. As such, in your current code, saying `greeting = "Goodbye from the main thread";` sets the main thread's version of this variable, not the thread you're running.

You can only set thread static variables from within the thread.

I would instead package all the state needed to pass to the subthread together in a class, and then pass a reference to that class as data in the thread startup function.

Also, be aware that [starting threads in ASP.NET code is generally a bad idea](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx).

Comment: With closures being available in C# I consider the `state` parameter to be mostly obsolete.